# windows terminal(oh my posh) not showing git status after whatever I have tried

Tags: windows-terminal, oh-my-posh

### description

1. I import posh-git but don't use its prompt style. and my windows terminal $PROFILE like:

   - ```
     Import-Module posh-git
     Import-Module oh-my-posh
     Set-PoshPrompt -Theme default
     #$env:POSH_GIT_ENABLED = $true
     ```
2. I have read the similar question [[Windows Terminal + oh-my-posh not showing git status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68228173/windows-terminal-oh-my-posh-not-showing-git-status) and made the theme file change, but it also doesn't work.

   - the "git" segment of the theme file like:

     ```json
         {
               "type": "git",
               "background": "p:green",
               "background_templates": [
                 "{{ if or (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }}p:yellow{{ end }}",
                 "{{ if and (gt .Ahead 0) (gt .Behind 0) }}p:red{{ end }}",
                 "{{ if gt .Ahead 0 }}#49416D{{ end }}",
                 "{{ if gt .Behind 0 }}#7A306C{{ end }}"
               ],
               "foreground": "p:black",
               "foreground_templates": [
                 "{{ if or (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }}p:black{{ end }}",
                 "{{ if and (gt .Ahead 0) (gt .Behind 0) }}p:white{{ end }}",
                 "{{ if gt .Ahead 0 }}p:white{{ end }}"
               ],
               "powerline_symbol": "\ue0b0",
               "properties": {
                 "display_status": true,
                 "display_stash_count": true,
                 "display_upstream_icon": true,
                 "branch_max_length": 25,
                 "fetch_status": true,
                 "fetch_upstream_icon": true,
                 "github_icon": "\uf7a3"
               },
               "style": "powerline",
               "template": " {{ if .UpstreamURL }}{{ url .UpstreamIcon .UpstreamURL }} {{ end }}{{ .HEAD }}{{ .BranchStatus }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uf044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }} \uf046 {{ .Staging.String }}{{ end }} "
         },
     ```

     all the display properties("display_status" ...) are true.

### image:

it doesn't display git status!! why??
[the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjR3I.jpg)

### Question

I just want to know whether oh-my-posh has deprecated the git status display ???

and I have read the [oh-my-posh Blog page](https://ohmyposh.dev/blog), there is no changes on git status display

Answer (score 3):

1. `oh-my-posh` has deprecated their PowerShell module and [is asking users to migrate](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/migrating).
   So as a first step, run the migration steps outlined in the docs and replace `Import-Module oh-my-posh` as well as `Set-PoshPrompt -Theme default` with, for example,

   ```
   oh-my-posh init pwsh --config ~/.custom.omp.json | Invoke-Expression
   ```
2. Uncomment

   ```
   #$env:POSH_GIT_ENABLED = $true
   ```

   so `posh-git` is enabled. The `posh-git` prompt [is disabled by default](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git):

   > PowerShell offers support for the `posh-git` module for autocompletion, but it is disabled by default. To enable this, set `$env:POSH_GIT_ENABLED = $true` in your `$PROFILE`.
3. In the [`posh-git` README](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/#customizing-the-posh-git-prompt), it says:

   > posh-git will not replace the prompt function if it has detected that you have your own, customized prompt function.

   Good, so this is what we're after: using `oh-my-posh` over the `posh-git` prompt. So how do we get the latter into the former?
4. In your `oh-my-posh.omp.json` configuration file, [add a *segment*](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/poshgit#sample-configuration) at a position of your choice:

   ```json
   {
     "type": "poshgit",
     "style": "powerline",
     "powerline_symbol": "\uE0B0",
     "foreground": "#ffffff",
     "background": "#0077c2"
   }
   ```

   The relevant difference here is that this is of type `poshgit`, not of type `git` anymore (the latter being the `oh-my-posh` "builtin" as far as I see).

This works for me™, as a first approximation. You'll need to add custom `foreground_template` magic etc. to further customize it, but these settings should allow the `posh-git` prompt to at least display from within your `oh-my-posh` one.